# Helm CLI - Can't add/override new env var via --set command

Tags: kubernetes, command-line-interface, kubernetes-helm, selenium-grid

I'm trying to config my Selenium Grid (chart) via Helm cli (can't override values.yaml at this level.. have to use helm cli"), and i need to add the next env var:
`SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=5`
I tried to command this:
`--set chromeNode.replicas=5 \ --set chromeNode.extraEnvironmentVariables='["SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS"="5"]' \`
but it doesn't work..

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.env: got "string", expected "array"
```

what is the right way to add/override this env var?

`--set chromeNode.extraEnvironmentVariables='["SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS"="5"]' \` 
expecting for sucessfull deployment

Link for chart: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/trunk/charts/selenium-grid

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Chart you linked, the value *chromeNode.extraEnvironmentalVariables* calls for a Kubernetes classic array of envs with its classic structure [ name: *env_name*, value: *env_value* ].

According to the [Helm Official Documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/), you have two possible solutions.

If you have **Helm >= 2.5** you can use the [flat array technique](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/#consider-how-users-will-use-your-values) using this notation in your command line:

```
helm install --set chromeNode.extraEnvironmentVariables[0].name="SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS" --set chromeNode.extraEnvironmentVariables[0].value=5
```

Clearly, the downside is that you have to pick an array index value arbitrarily.

If you have **Helm >=3.0** you can use the **--set-json** option and notate everything in JSON as per the official documentations suggest.

```
helm install --set-json 'chromeNode.extraEnvironmentVariables=[{"name":"SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS","value":"5"}]'
```

A belate response but a response anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with:

```bash
--set chromeNode.extraEnvironmentVariables."SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS"="5"
```

Comment: it doesn’t work..
 
UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.env: got "map", expected "array"

Comment: @DolevShoval link of your helm chart please ?

Comment: Thanks for helping
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/trunk/charts/selenium-grid